# Possible to create Oracle regular expression that's able to match NULL?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

In Oracle, is it possible to match both a particular string format and an empty string using a single regex?

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT 1
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('12345', '^([1-5]{5})|NULL$');

SELECT 1
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('', '^([1-5]{5})|NULL$');

SELECT 1
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(NULL, '^([1-5]{5})|NULL$');
```

where the 'NULL' portion of the regex is treated as a character class rather than a string literal and all three queries return 1.

I'm writing some data validation routines and would like to store/use just one regex to determine both the format and whether the input string can be empty -- rather than specifying those validation rules seperately for each data element.

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can do so directly, but you could use `nvl` to make null values show up as a blank string or the string 'NULL'.

```
SELECT 1
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(NVL(value, 'NULL'), '^([1-5]{5})|NULL$');
```

Answer (score 5):

One option : Use

```
where regexp_like(expr, '^([1-5]{5})$') or (expr is null)
```

Comment: +1, this solution doesn't rely on any magic values... once the syntax has been corrected... REGEXP_LIKE(expr, '^([1-5]{5})$)

Comment: ironic... my syntax correction introduced a syntax error... :(

Comment: Well, I was really looking for a single regular expression rather than an additional predicate.  Codebender has a solution that meets that criterion.

Comment: yes, Codebender's solution is good - but instead of an additional predicate it uses an additional function call. (not that that's a problem, mind you, just saying)

Comment: "\s" also works to match an empty char, fyi.

 where regexp_like(nvl(expr,' '), 'abc|\s');

Comment: Thanks for your help babyLisper.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution:
REXEXP_LIKE(NVL(col, '*'), '&colNameQuery')

Then the user would use "*" as the query parameter for nulls and everything else.